# Will I see a performance hit if I use native API calls like get_the_title() instead of $post->post_title?

Tags: cache, performance

Let's say I've already got the $post object through some earlier process of looping through an array of IDs and using get_post() on each one of them, storing the resulting object in some array.

Later on, I want to loop through that array and do something with each post. I already have a $my_post object, so I could `echo $my_post->post_title`, or I could get fancy and `echo apply_filters('the_title', $my_post->post_title, $my_post->ID)` or I could just use the native `get_the_title($my_post->ID)`.

Here's where my performance question comes in. How reliable is the native cache (I'm not talking about some crazy plugin, just the built-in `wp_cache_get($post_id, 'posts')` etc..)?

I guess what I'm asking is: what is the likelihood that get_the_title() will dip back into the DB and re-grab the post, as opposed to using the cache, and would I be better off from a performance perspective just using the object data that I already have? Clearly you get more sugar if you use the built-in stuff. But does it risk going back to the DB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Template tags rely on global `$post` (unless you explicitly provide something else to those that support it. So either:

- they get something from that variable (no reason to go for it in database)
- or they don't (then they fail because they have no clue what you want)

Under most normal circumstances there is no reason to worry about impact of template tags. That only comes into play if you start dealing with crazy amount of posts and/or apply overly complex filters.

**Update after discussion in comments**

`get_post()` always tries to invoke cache before it makes database call. Cache gets purged by functions that modify posts explicitly ( see [`clean_post_cache()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/clean_post_cache) ) or expires naturally.

Comment: Let's not oversimplify my question, Rarst. Actually, if you dig into the code, you see that template tags are significantly more sophisticated than that. At least the `get_` variety. IF the global $post object has been defined, AND no ID has been supplied, then the global $post object is used; however, if the ID is supplied, then it goes to the cache. If the cache has nothing for that ID, then it goes to the database.

Comment: @Tom sorry if I missed on details, was late for me at the time. I am not sure I completely understand your concern. It's correct that if you have loaded post once with `get_post()` then subsequent calls for this post will go to cache. What do you think might go wrong here in context of your usage?

Comment: thanks for the follow-up. I think I just haven't dug deeply enough into wp_cache to understand how _consistently_ something is cached. Is EVERY get_post() request cached for the session? Does the cache get purged after a certain limit? I believe that it's pretty safe to do `get_the_permalink($id)` and then `get_the_title($id)` and it will NOT be 2 separate database calls. Do you agree?

Comment: @Tom Auger yes, `get_post()` always tries to invoke cache before it makes database call. Cache gets purged by functions that modify posts explicitly ( see [clean_post_cache()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/clean_post_cache) ) or expires naturally.